# Uncaught TypeError: r.existsSync is not a function in Angular 6 and Electron desktop application

Tags: angular, electron, angular5, upgrade, angular6

I am upgrading a desktop application to Angular 6 from Angular 5 and Electron 2 framework but getting this error when I run/build the app: `npm start` which runs `electron .`.

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: r.existsSync is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (main.4ff68b38699fd48ecfa7.js:1)
at Object.vbkW (main.4ff68b38699fd48ecfa7.js:1)
at p (runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js:1)
at Object.zUnb (main.4ff68b38699fd48ecfa7.js:1)
at p (runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js:1)
at Object.7 (main.4ff68b38699fd48ecfa7.js:1)
at p (runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js:1)
at n (runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js:1)
at Array.e [as push] (runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js:1)
at main.4ff68b38699fd48ecfa7.js:1
```

I think this is an issue only with Angular 6. I could not understand much from this error stacktrace. The application is working perfectly fine in Angular 5.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Something must be broken with the packaged bundle. [This issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7300) looks very similar.

Could you try to replace `require('fs')` with `window.require('fs')` as suggested there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but now its throwing the error: `main.ts(5,25): error TS2339: Property 'require' does not exist on type 'Window'.`. I might not be doing it correctly.

Comment: @atik, I believe that You no longer need it, but for anyone interested: it seems required to have `nodeIntegration` set to `true` in `BrowserWindow` options as described here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7300#issuecomment-493077796 .

Answer (score 0):

did you import the module using `require`.

```
var r= require('fs');
```

Comment: Wouldn't you get a *"Cannot read property 'existsSync' of undefined"* error if you didn't import at all? I think the error is coming from somewhere else.